# Persist user name when login fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My app is built on HTML (bootstrap), JavaScript (JQuery).

My login form has an input for user name and password. How can I persist the user name when a login fails? Cross-browser?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Comment: Please post the code you're already tried.

Comment: Easiest way would be using the server-side language that your action page is using to output the username to the input field's value.

Comment: You have to save it to a session variable in your app. JavaScript won't help.

Comment: On the server, when you verify the username and password, if the credentials are invalid, insert a record in your database with the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery to store it in a cookie:

```
$.cookie("username",theUserName);
```

Comment: This requires the jQuery cookie plugin. It is not a native part of jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain old JavaScript if you can't use jQuery plugins.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably my first go-to solution would be to store it in a session with php.  Here's a good, basic example:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp